# How do we get he console access status of an AWS IAM user? boto3 doesn't have a direct program for it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

client = boto3.client("iam")

gets the users but there is no direct function here to get the status of the console access

I am looking here for a direct function:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to an IAM user's access to login to the AWS web console, and not something else such as the ability to create an SSH or SSM connection to an EC2 instance, then you are looking for [get_login_profile](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam/client/get_login_profile.html).

> A login profile is created when you create a password for the user to access the Amazon Web Services Management Console. If the user does not exist or does not have a password, the operation returns a 404 ( NoSuchEntity) error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have used the same function to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Using `get_login_profile()`, I am able to to check console access. It's somewhat indirect. Like only users with console access will get a response to this call, while others will get a 404 error since the profile won't be loaded.

Comment: This looks like it should be a comment on the accepted answer, rather than an answer.